# Python+Selenium: which "find_element_by" alternatives suite in this case?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm very new in selenium and trying to figure out which alternatives "find_element_by_..." is best in this case.

```html
<input _ngcontent-wsq-c70="" type="text" formcontrolname="username" onfocusrestaurantcolor="" class="form-control form-input ng-dirty ng-touched ng-invalid is-invalid" placeholder="username" style="border-color: rgb(206, 212, 218); box-shadow: unset;">
```

What I have already tried:
**element = driver.find_element_by_name("//input[@type='text']")**

--> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="//input[@type='text']"]"}

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @KunduK 

element = driver.find_element_by_name("//input[@type='text']")

--> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="//input[@type='text']"]"}

Comment: add some more examples, if it's possible provide page example

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `xpath`.

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'][@formcontrolname='username']")
```

Comment: I get always an error message. I don't know if i'm doing something wrong or not:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='text'][@formcontrolname='username']"}

Comment: Interesting is that, when I make an emoty file with only this line of HTML code, and run your suggestion code in Selenium, i get the result, but with the whole html-file, I get an error message.

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei : The element must be inside an iframe? you need to switch to iframe first. Please check the element inside any iframe tag?

Comment: You are right, the <input> is inside <form>, maybe you would give me a sample how I switch to form first?

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei : Not `form` I said `iframe` tow are different thing. Check input element inside `iframe`?

Comment: there is no iframe in the code, but "form".

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei : If possible share your url?

Comment: I found the problem. I used "time.sleep(5)", now it works. - Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Because of Angular in code, I tried using this code, and works fine:

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text'][@formcontrolname='username']"))
    )
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'][@formcontrolname='username']")
    element.send_keys('t1')
except:
    driver.quit()

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei : Instead of  `presence_of_element_located() ` use `element_to_be_clickable()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use different bunch of selectors, I usually use smth like this:

```
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, selector)
```

By. is class factory with number of provided selectors types:

```
ID = "id"
XPATH = "xpath"
LINK_TEXT = "link text"
PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
NAME = "name"
TAG_NAME = "tag name"
CLASS_NAME = "class name"
CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

you can use here, like css selector, or xpath:

```
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control form-input ng-dirty ng-touched ng-invalid is-invalid']")
```

or

```
el = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.form-input.ng-dirty.ng-touched.ng-invalid.is-invalid")
```

or

```
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='username'")
```

it depends on you mostly what you prefer more or sometimes, what is more flexible for using

while developing, you can even collaborate with developers and use custom properties to make/have elements more unique